# I need help making a for loop in java to make random lines appear in an applet

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, for-loop, random

I need help creating random lines in java using Math.random(); 
I need to make 100 lines but as a newbie, I need help.
I started with this for(int i = 0; i <100; i++)
I don't know what do do after.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "random lines"?

Comment: http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw114/assets/images/lines1.jpg

Comment: Can you show your code so far and where this randomization would need to be in it? Drawing in java can be a bit weird.

Comment: Then just generate 4 random numbers on each iteration of the loop (2 pairs of x,y coordinates), and then draw a line from one x,y coordinate to the other one. I'm not sure exactly what you're using to draw the line, but it shouldn't be that hard to figure out. You should probably multiply your number by some value that makes sense in order to fit in your window since `Math.random()` generates a number from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: i would think that i would randomize it right after the loop but I'm extra confused how to randomize each variable in g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

Comment: ok  Jackmerius, i will try that, thanks for the help, you guys are quick!

Answer (score -1):

Just generate your 4 numbers inside the loop, and use them to draw your line. This will give you numbers between 0.0 and 100.0, which you can always tweak.

```
int numLines = 100;

Random rand = Random();
for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
    double x1 = r.nextDouble() * 100;
    double y1 = r.nextDouble() * 100;
    double x2 = r.nextDouble() * 100;
    double y2 = r.nextDouble() * 100;

    g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
```

Comment: Come on, at least say why you down-voted. The OP didn't post any code, so there's no context for this really, but it should work. It simply gets random x,y coordinates, and draws a line between them (100 times).